# Disable folder auto-creation in OneDrive under Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, motorola-moto-e, onedrive, motorola-moto-e3

OneDrive for Android 6.0 Marshmallow keeps adding "Email attachments" and "Documents" folder to my root OneDrive folder each time I open this application under my Moto E3.

Is there any way to block / disable this annoying feature?

Is this something OneDrive-specific or Marshmallow-specific. If I switch to Dropbox, will I be able to fully control what is added to my cloud-folder / block automatic creation of some strange folders?

Comment: [For desktop version it is not possible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/odwork-odfiles/why-does-onedrive-automatically-create-documents/3479b165-c96a-41a9-9870-41ebc7b0fc8e) according to this and same probably for Android version since they are meant to be compatible?  For preventing or deleting *root* may be needed. Is your device rooted?

Comment: My phone is not rooted. I am aware of forum thread you have linked, but I would be reluctant in calling this compatibility, since OneDrive for Android creates different folders than OneDrive for desktop Windows and since OneDrive for Windows Mobile does not auto-create anything. Paths are root = Both folders mentioned in the question are auto-created in root folder of my OneDrive for Android.